# No se configurar el botón siguiente en un Reproductor de Video (KOTLIN)

Tags: kotlin, botón, video, next, videoview

Me falta programar la lógica en el botón siguiente y previo para el reproductor de video usando KOTLIN, alguien sabe como hacerlo? Gracias!!

```kotlin
    //UBICACION DE TODOS LOS VIDEOS
    val clipsList = listOf(
        R.raw.cara_7,
        R.raw.cara_3,
        R.raw.cara_8)

    val index = 0

    //ACCESO AL VIDEO SEGUN INDIQUE LA VARIABLE index
    val videoView : VideoView = findViewById(R.id.video)
    videoView.setVideoURI(
        Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                + packageName + "/" + clipsList[index])
    )
   
     //BOTON NEXT
    val btnNext : ImageButton = findViewById(R.id.btnNext)
    btnNext.setOnClickListener {
    //Acá no sé que poner, Probé con (index++) pero no anda. Falta 
    algo...
    }
```

Comment: Bienvenido. Si agregas el código probablemente alguien te pueda ayudar. Sino la pregunta va camino a ser cerrada y que en estas condiciones no puede ser respondida. No te preocupes si eso pasa, una vez que la pregunta esté bien puedes solicitar su reapertura. Más información en el [help].

Comment: ok, ahora agrego el codigo!

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: Me sale este error: Parece que tu publicación es mayormente código; por favor, añade más detalles.

Comment: @Mateo Pude publicar una parte del codigo, ¿hace falta algo más?, quise agregar los iconos pero no pude, igual no sé si son necesarios!

Comment: ¿Si vuelves a escribir la línea de setVideoURI pero con `index + 1` no funciona?

Comment: @Mateo Funciona pero si lo hago manual, osea cambiando yo la linea de codigo de setVideoURI, pero con los botonoes no cambia el indice

Comment: Seguro que probaste con `videoView.setVideoURI( Uri.parse("android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + clipsList[index + 1]) )`?

Comment: @Mateo si hice eso, y me cambia de video, pero que pongo en los botones next y back?? index +1 no me funciona, gracias por tu interes? ;)

Comment: Me refiero a poner eso en el listener del botón.

Comment: @Mateo Recién probé y me funciono!! pero solo avanza 1 no sigue hasta el tercero...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes aumentar la variable `index` y cargar el vídeo con `videoView.setVideoURI`. Podrías crear una función para eso y llamarla desde `btnNext.setOnClickListener`:

```
var index = 0

fun avanzar(){
    index++
    val uri = "android.resource://" + packageName + "/" + clipsList[index]
    videoView.setVideoURI(Uri.parse(uri))
}

fun onCreate(){
    // ...

    btnNext.setOnClickListener {
        avanzar()
    }
}
```

Debes reemplazar `val` por `var` en la declaración de la variable `index`. Ya que `val` declara una variable de solo lectura. `var` permite reasignarla.

Te dejo la tarea de limitar `index`para que sea una posición válida.

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta @Mateo...mañana te hablo y te comento como me fue!

Comment: Hola mateo, probé lo que me indicaste pero, cuando hago clic en el botón next me dice: No se puede reproducir este video.

Y el error que figura en consola es:
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)

Comment: @Daniel Que extraño. Es casi lo mismo que probaste anoche y te funcionó.

Comment: Me marca error en la variable que esta dentro de la función avanzar()                                                                                                                        val uri= "android.resource://packageName/"+ clipList[index + 1]

Comment: Ahora me anda el código, copie mal una parte! Gracias por la ayuda, te tengo que calificar???

Comment: @Daniel Si la respuesta te ayudó a solucionar el problema, puedes marcarla con el tilde verde.